# Pagination using jquery ajax in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using the below code to create a pagination

```
  function paginationGenerate(page,pageCount) {
alert("hai");
alert(page);
var pagination = "<ul class=\"pagination\"><li><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"paginationGenerate(checkPrevious(" + page + ")," + pageCount + ") \">&laquo;</a></li>";

/* Page Range Calculation */
var range = pageRange(page, pageCount);
var start = range.start;
var end = range.end;

for (var page_id = start; page_id <= end; page_id++) {
    if (page_id != page) pagination += "<li><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"paginationGenerate(" + page_id + "," + pageCount + ")\">" + page_id + "</a></li>";
    else pagination += "<li class='active'><span>" + page_id + "</span></li>";
}
pagination += "<li><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"paginationGenerate(checkNext(" + page + "," + pageCount + ")," + pageCount + ")\">&raquo;</a></li></ul>";

/* Appending Pagination */
$('.pagination').remove();
$('body').append(pagination);
```

}

```
 /* Pagination Navigation */
 function checkPrevious(id) {
if (id > 1) {
    return (id - 1);
}
return 1;
```

}

```
 /* Pagination Navigation */
  function checkNext(id, pageCount) {
if (id < pageCount) {
    return (id + 1);
}
return id;
```

}

```
  /* Page Range calculation Method for Pagination */
  function pageRange(page, pageCount) {

var start = page - 2,
    end = page + 2;

if (end > pageCount) {
    start -= (end - pageCount);
    end = pageCount;
}
if (start <= 0) {
    end += ((start - 1) * (-1));
    start = 1;
}

end = end > pageCount ? pageCount : end;

return {
    start: start,
    end: end
};
```

}

```
 function pageNo() {
console.log("Hello");
}
```

And then, the below code is for viewing the records with pagination:

```
  function  view_data()
  {
   //alert("Display");

    $.ajax({

        url     :   "operations.php?funct1=view",
        type    :   "POST",
        dataType: "html",

        success: function(result) {
                //console.log(result);
                 paginationGenerate(2,3); 
                $('#view').html(result);    

              },            
        });
      $('#display').hide(); 

      return false;
```

}

I'm using seperate functions for CRUD operations, so in my `operations.php`, i'm having the below code to execute the view:

```
  if(isset($_GET['funct1']))
 {
     $func_get  =   $_GET['funct1'];        
     if($func_get   ==  'view')
     {          
        $val->view_data();      
     }
 }

 In a class `db_operations` i'm having the below code:

  function view_data()
{
    $tbl_name="ajax_insert";
    $num_page =10;

    if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
    $start_from = ($page-1) * $num_page; 

    $view ="SELECT * FROM `ajax_insert` LIMIT $start_from, $num_page";
    //echo $view;
    $exe_view = mysql_query($view);
    if($exe_view === FALSE) 
    { 
          die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    }
    $num = mysql_num_rows($exe_view);
    if($num == 0)
    {
        echo "<div class='success-align'><span class='failed'>No Available Data Here!!Please Insert a data</span></div>";

    }
    else
    {
        echo '<table class="table_data">
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>User Name</th>
                  <th>Address</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Mobile</th> 
                  <th>City</th>
                  ';
           $i=1;
          while($fetch_details = mysql_fetch_assoc($exe_view))
            {
                $slNo = $i+$start_from; //to display the record number continuously 
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$slNo."</td>";
                echo "<td>".ucfirst($fetch_details['user_name'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".ucfirst($fetch_details['address'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$fetch_details['email']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$fetch_details['mobile']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$fetch_details['city']."</td>";                    
              ?>
             <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return edit_funct('<?php echo $fetch_details['id']; ?>')">Edit</a></td>
             <td><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" onclick="return delete_funct('<?php echo $fetch_details['id'];?>')">Delete</a></td>

             </tr>
        <?php
        $i++;
        }
    echo '</table>';

    //echo pagination($tbl_name,$num_page,$page); 
 }
}
```

From this how can i get my pagination using ajax.When i'm using the above code,it shows

[image]

When i click it,it wont move with proper records.

I didn't do this in previous sections.So I need a help to do pagination in ajax:(

I have no idea to do this.Please help me!!

But I need to create a pagination in jquery ajax.How to achieve it in jquery ajax?

Comment: someone please guide me:(

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps : https://jsfiddle.net/qsLp6ajL/4/

```
function paginationGenerate(page,pageCount) {
/* page - current page, pageCount - total pages */ 
var pagination = "<ul class=\"pagination\"><li><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"paginationGenerate(checkPrevious(" + page + ")) \">&laquo;</a></li>";

/* Page Range Calculation */
var range = pageRange(page, pageCount);
var start = range.start;
var end = range.end;

for (var page_id = start; page_id <= end; page_id++) {
    if (page_id != page) pagination += "<li><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"paginationGenerate(" + page_id + ")\">" + page_id + "</a></li>";
    else pagination += "<li class='active'><span>" + page_id + "</span></li>";
}
pagination += "<li><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"paginationGenerate(checkNext(" + page + "," + pageCount + "))\">&raquo;</a></li></ul>";

/* Appending Pagination */
$('.pagination').remove();
$('body').append(pagination);
}

/* Pagination Navigation */
function checkPrevious(id) {
    if (id > 1) {
       return (id - 1);
    }
    return 1;
}

/* Pagination Navigation */
function checkNext(id, pageCount) {
    if (id < pageCount) {
        return (id + 1);
    }
return id;
}

/* Page Range calculation Method for Pagination */
function pageRange(page, pageCount) {

   var start = page - 2,
       end = page + 2;

   if (end > pageCount) {
      start -= (end - pageCount);
      end = pageCount;
   }
   if (start <= 0) {
      end += ((start - 1) * (-1));
      start = 1;
   }

   end = end > pageCount ? pageCount : end;

   return {
      start: start,
       end: end
   };
}
```

Comment: where could i call this js function?

Comment: I've edited the code slightly. Call this Js within your ajax success function. Pass the current page number and total number of pages as parametres.

Comment: actually i'm using a function for pagination in php

Comment: why i'm not getting alert when click my delete link?

Comment: try to debug using F12 key in your browser

Answer (score 0):

Did you googled to find an answer? This is a very easy and common topic and you can find nice articles by googling.

Read below articles:

http://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-jquery-ajax-php/

http://www.infotuts.com/ajax-pagination-mysql-php-and-jquery/

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your response...i have already referred the above links you are provided.wait i will edit my question..